# fun search shows only one item at a time

Tags: kotlin, mvvm

I am begginer programming. i write the note app with kotlin and using mvvm, Room, LiveData
In the search section, every word I search shows only the first item, even if the searched word is not in that item.
fun search and getData in dao:

```
 @Query("SELECT * FROM note_table")
fun getAllNotes(): LiveData<List<Note>>

  @Query("SELECT * FROM note_table WHERE title LIKE '%'|| :searching ||'%' OR subtitle LIKE '%'|| :searching ||'%' OR note LIKE '%'|| :searching ||'%'")
fun searchNotes(searching: String): List<Note>
```

fun search and getData in repository:

```
 fun getAllNote(): LiveData<List<Note>>{
    return  noteDao.getAllNotes()
}

 fun searchNote(searching: String):List<Note>{
    return noteDao.searchNotes(searching)
}
```

fun search and getData in viewModel:

```
 fun getAllNote():LiveData<List<Note>>{
    return noteRepository.getAllNote()
}

 fun searchNote(searching: String):List<Note> {
    return noteRepository.searchNote(searching)
}
```

fun refreshData in adapter:

```
 @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
fun refreshData(newNote: List<Note>){
    data.clear()
    data.addAll(newNote)
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

fun search in mainActivity:

```
 binding.edtSearch.addTextChangedListener {editTextInput->
      val searchText = editTextInput.toString()
      if(searchText.isNotEmpty()){
          adapter.refreshData(screenViewModel.searchNote(searchText))
      }else{
          screenViewModel.getAllNote().observe(this) { notes ->
              adapter.refreshData(notes)
          }
      }
  }
```

I even tried this instead of the above function:

```
 binding.edtSearch.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
        override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {
        }

        override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
            val searchText = s.toString()
            if (searchText.isNotEmpty()) {
                
                    adapter.refreshData(screenViewModel.searchNote(searchText))
                
            } else {
                screenViewModel.getAllNote().observe(this@MainActivity) { notes->
                    adapter.refreshData(notes as ArrayList<Note>)
                }
            }
        }

        override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
        }
    })
```